# Check if table exists or not using hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

In my project we are using hibernate connection and creating the tables .I want create table api calling that time i want check table is there or not status.

I need alternate code for hibernate

```
Connection c = ...
DatabaseMetaData dbm = c.getMetaData();`enter code here`
// check if "employee" table is there
ResultSet tables = dbm.getTables(null, null, "employee", null);
if (tables.next()) {
  // Table exists
}
else {
  // Table does not exist
}
```

Comment: Hi Raja, your goal with this question is not very clear. If you are asking for working code, the question is too broad. You might have more luck if you restrict the problem, possibly sharing the code you wrote, and ask for help/suggestion/improvement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate gives you access to the underlying JDBC connection with the `doWork` method:

```
session.doWork(new Work() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        DatabaseMetaData dbm = connection.getMetaData();
        ResultSet tables = dbm.getTables(null, null, "employee", null);
        if (tables.next()) {
            // ...
    }
});
```